# What is written on the side of the 'mystery key' on a IBM PC 3180 keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, history

What is written on the side of the ['mystery key'](https://superuser.com/questions/290814/purpose-of-a-mystery-key-on-ibm-pc-3270-keyboard) on an IBM PC 3180 keyboard?

[image]

To be more specific, I'm talking about the text seen here...

[image]

Comment: I think that is the any key symbol, that you hit when the program says hit "any key".

Comment: Lets see. Is it a question about computer hardware or software? Yes. Is it a question with a definite answer ? yes. is it subjective, no. Looks like a perfectly relevant question to me.

Comment: This wouldn't be as bad if it was a different key... the problem I see is: the key still has the same purpose, there is just an extra symbol on the side... I don't know about anyone else here but I can't make out what that symbol is.

Comment: @JohnDR: Well, I think they wouldn't implement an actual `any` key...

Comment: @peth: Sorry for having interpreted that as a playful joke (I guess I'm also a bit too alert because I'm in an exam period and have a lot of stress burden me) as it is of course a nice comment to read towards others. But imagine being interested in this and asking it and then having such a comment put this question or any of us in a bad daylight, I would've simply agreed or be less affected with a comment that just pointed out the flaws in a non-jocular way. I'll try to ignore jokes from now or place more polite canned bin responses that question why a bad daylight comment has been placed...

Comment: The "PC" in the title doesn't really apply since this is a terminal keyboard not a personal computer keyboard.

Comment: @Brian: Can you back that up? Because this is listed as a PC keyboard as far as I can see and can be connected to a PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the key itself is effectively "Delete" (or "strikeout" as I would like to think of that symbol) the picture is not very clear and I cannot find any clearer images on the internet.

Looking at the rather fuzzy top image I believe that what may be there is effectively

<kbd>abc(strikeout)</kbd>

as in

[image: a]

but with "abc" and so denoting that it is to delete an entire word as opposed to an individual letter.

You can just about make it out if you squint a bit and use a bit of imagination...

[image]

I found a slightly better angle [here](http://www.9999hp.net/botnet/serverbig.jpg) and it's just looking more and more like "abc(strikeout)" to me

Comment: Is that a computer in a cardboard box that you linked???? Or is it a cardboard box case?

Comment: And is that a USB cord attached to a plastic bottle??? what a strange picture...

Comment: @Kyle, I've read through the page I found it on and I'm honestly not convinced just what it is really meant to be... see for yourself: http://www.9999hp.net/botnet/

Comment: OK @Mokubai that totally created more questions than answers... I love the "terminals" which are just plastic bottles with keyboards "plugged in" to the top. The whole page is quite comical..

Comment: I just got it... it's a "bot net" or bottle net XD

Comment: @Kyle Oh gawd, I hadn't thought of that.  /headdesk   I was too busy concentrating on the key to notice the awful joke staring me in the face.

Comment: I thought that was a water coolant setup.

Answer (score 4):

On the [Affirmative 1227T](http://www.seasip.info/Misc/1227T.html), the corresponding key is marked 'Delete' on the top and 'DelWd'  ("Delete word"?) on the front. So I'd guess that it's the same strikeout symbol, only striking out a word rather than a character.